# Nginx Locations and Connection Permissions

Tags: nginx, ddos

I'm suffering a brute force attack, I need to look the access log and get the routes to block:

```
location /foo/{ deny all;}
location /foo2/{deny all;}
```

Since there are infinite routes I would need to spend a good time looking all the access log to block connections at those specific routes.

Instead of denying specific routes could I configure nginx to block connections on all other routes that don't exists in my application?

[]'s

Pedro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a list of first level folders and then you can block access to all not of them with a access required

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    map $request_uri $allowed_routes {
        ~^/(css|assets|js)/ "off";
        / "off";
        default "Not allowed";
    }

    server {
        auth_basic $allowed_routes;
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/html/.htpasswd;
        location / {
            echo "You can reach API $uri and $args, $arg_hash_folder";
        }
    }
}
```

You might consider other approaches also, but this one works well for me